# R: Creating a vector with certain values from another vector

Tags: r

So I have a csv file with column headers `ID`, `Score`, and `Age`. 
So in `R` I have,

```
data <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)

attach(data)
```

I would like to create two new vectors with people's scores whos age are below 70 and above 70 years old. I thought there was a nice a quick way to do this but I cant find it any where. Thanks for any help

Example of what data looks like

ID, Score, Age

1, 20, 77

2, 32, 65

.... etc

And I am trying to make 2 vectors where it consists of all peoples scores who are younger than 70 and all peoples scores who are older than 70

Comment: try www.google.com :)

Comment: @Mateusz1981 what should I google

Comment: Please put a reproducible example or the sample input data and expected output..this way, community understands your problem and replies you. Thanks!

Comment: @HankManks how to subset the data set, 1000s of examples

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `data` looks like this:

```
   Score Age
1      1  29
2      5  39
3      8  40
4      3  89
5      5  31
6      6  23
7      7  75
8      3   3
9      2  23
10     6  54
..     .  ..
```

you can use

```
df_old <- data[data$Age >= 70,]
df_young <- data[data$Age < 70,]
```

which gives you

```
> df_old
   Score Age
4      3  89
7      7  75
11     7  97
13     3 101
16     5  89
18     5  89
19     4  96
20     3  97
21     8  75
```

and

```
> df_young
   Score Age
1      1  29
2      5  39
3      8  40
5      5  31
6      6  23
8      3   3
9      2  23
10     6  54
12     4  23
14     2  23
15     4  45
17     7  53
```

PS: if you only want the scores and not the age, you could use this:

```
df_old <- data[data$Age >= 70, "Score"]
df_young <- data[data$Age < 70, "Score"]
```